# Taylor second order approximation for an implicit curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm given the curve:

$$f(x,y)=e^{x^2+y^2}+3y-4x^2-1=0$$

and I want to find the second order Taylor approximation for y(x) at the point (0,0):

$$y(x)\approx y(0)+ y'(0)x+\frac{1}{2!}y''(0)x^2+...$$

I thought about finding the derivatives with the chain rule like:

$$y'(x)=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$$

But I don't have $y(0)$ and I don't know how to get it. Is my approach incorrect?

I appreciate any tip!

Comment: How is $y(x)$ defined? You only defined $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes. $y(x)$ is not given so I'm assuming that I need to do some implicit derivation there

Answer (score 1):

You may perform implicit differentiation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2(4-e^{x^2+y^2})x}{3+2y e^{x^2+y^2}},$$ hence at $(0,0)$ we have $y'(0) = 0$.  Repeating the process yields

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{-8 e^{3
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)} \left(x^2+y^2\right)+8 e^{2
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)} \left(8 x^2+y (4 y-3)\right)-2
   e^{x^2+y^2} \left(16 y \left(8 x^2 y+6 x^2-3\right)+82
   x^2+9\right)+72}{\left(2 y
   e^{x^2+y^2}+3\right)^3}$$

and again at $(0,0)$ we obtain $$y''(0) = 2.$$

This kind of thing is best left to a computer.  It is not strictly necessary to express the second derivative in terms of $x$ an $y$ only; if you know the lower order derivatives, the computation can be simplified.

The plot below shows the curve $f(x,y)$ in blue and the second-order approximation $y = x^2$ in orange:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was doing, but I'm still missing $y(0)$

Comment: @MarianaVivas When $y = 0$, we simply solve $f(x,0) = 0$ to obtain $x = 0$.  There are of course other roots as the figure shows, $x \approx \pm 1.52861$.

Answer (score 1):

You do know $y(0)$... Since $(0,0)$ belongs to the curve, $y(0)=0$. You can get $y'(0)$ and $y''(0)$ by differentiating the equality. Assuming $y=y(x)$,
$$
e^{x^2+y^2} + 3y-4x^2-1 = 0 \Rightarrow (2x + 2 y' y)e^{x^2+y^2}+3 y'-8x =0.
$$

substituting $x=0$, you get $y'(0)=0$. Differentiating again,
$$
(2+2y'' y +2y'y')e^{x^2+y^2}+(2x+2y'y)^2e^{x^2+y^2}+3y''-8 = 0$$

and substituting $x=0$ you get $y''(0) =2$.

So, finally
$$
y(x) \approx y(0) + y'(0) x  + \frac 12 y''(0) x^2 = x^2.
$$